# Read latest journal articles on your phone?

Tags: publications, journals

I'm not sure if this is the right stackexchange.

But i was wondering if there is a way to select a number of journals in your field, and have the latest articles of those journals on your phone, so that you can open the latest articles of specific journals with the tap of a finger.

Given how addictive smartphone apps can be, it seems like its better to be addicted to reading journal articles than to facebook.

Take an analogy with newspapers: A newspaper is an aggregation of relevant new information. When you read the newspaper you're not beforehand specifying that you want to know something about a war in the middle east. Its just that something happened in the middle east that you didn't know about and couldn't have searched for. Essentially I'm looking for a (metaphorical) "newspaper of journal articles on my phone"

Comment: Are you asking for an app? Or can you? Or should you?

Comment: @SolarMike, it might be an app, or some way to use an app thats not meant for it.

Comment: So what would you want it to do that pointing your browser at scholar.google.com won't?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, I don't see how that is not obvious from my question.

Comment: @Programmer2134 I don't see how using scholar.google.com is not a solution. Perhaps you can elaborate.

Comment: @user2768, maybe I'm unaware of what google scholar can do... But as far as I understand, you have to search with google scholar. You have to write what you want. you have to also know before hand what you want. I am talking about getting the journal articles feeded to you, so you can open them with one tap, without having to search for them.

Comment: Try https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?sciupd=1 which does exactly what you're asking

Comment: @Programmer2134 when you search for something, don’t you know what you are looking for ? Unless it’s inspiration...

Comment: I think my understanding, and that of others, is directly related to the clarity of the original question - the info that has come out via comments would have made the original question so much easier to answer...

Comment: @Programmer2134, if you edit your question, then you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSS (Rich Site Summary) is an open standard that many journals use to deliver their latest tables of content and abstracts.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS):

> RSS is a type of web feed which allows users to access updates to online content in a standardized, computer-readable format.

Simply download any feed reader app to subscribe to the RSS feeds of your favorite journals. If you find an abstract of interest, click on the title to be redirected to the respective repository where you can usually read or download the article in pdf or html format with your preferred browser or reader. Or you may want to save the paper from there with a reference management app such as Zotero or Mendeley.

Unfortunately, more and more journals seem to be discontinuing their RSS feeds in favor of e-mail alerts, which I find less useful.

Answer (score 1):

Google Scholar will recommend manuscripts to you: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?sciupd=1.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you:

https://www.researcher-app.com/

Comment: Please expand on this answer to explain what this app does. We do not accept link-only answers.

Comment: This seems very good, but unfortunately only works for life sciences and natural sciences